# Write a investment python code using loops

Tags: python

I also have to use a while of for loop.
Here is what I have so far but when I run it, it doesn't stop

```
initial_investment = int(input('Enter Investment Amount:'))
annual_intrest = float(input('Enter Annual Investment Amount:'))
years = int(input('Enter Number of Years:'))

while years>0 and initial_investment>0:
    monthly_interest = annual_intrest/12
    months = years/12
    future_val_years = initial_investment*(1+annual_intrest)**years
    future_val_months = initial_investment*(1+monthly_interest)**months
    print('Accumulated value (monthly) is:', future_val_months)
    print('Accumulated value (yearly) is:', future_val_years)
```

Comment: this may not be important to your question, but it looks like `months=years/12` should instead be `months=years*12`

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Comment: Well, years and initial_investment are never changed in your while loop so once your program enters the loop it is never coming out.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the [tag:basic] programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need while loop in your question, and number of months = years * 12

```
initial_investment = int(input('Enter Investment Amount:'))
annual_intrest = float(input('Enter Annual Investment Amount:'))
years = int(input('Enter Number of Years:'))

monthly_interest = annual_intrest/12
months = years*12

future_val_years = initial_investment * (1+annual_intrest)**years
future_val_months=initial_investment*(1+monthly_interest)**months

print('Accumulated value (monthly) is:', future_val_months)
print('Accumulated value (yearly) is:', future_val_years)
```